# How can I trigger a function when a bound value changes?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code in my ViewModel:

```
public partial class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    string _newName;

    public string NewName {
        get => _newName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _newName, value);
    }

}
```

Is there a way that I can capture the change of newName and every time a character changes call a method?

Comment: subscribe to PropertyChanged, or just add some code to the setter

Comment: Could you give an example of those solutions you suggest?  Which do you feel would be the most simple and and advantage between one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subscribe to `PropertyChanged`

```
myViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s,e) {
  
  if (e.PropertyName == "NewName") {
    //do something
  }
}
```

or add code to the setter

```
string _newName;

public string NewName {
    get { return _newName; }
    set {
      // do something
      SetProperty(ref _newName, value);
    }
}
```